# ¿Por qué "vida capulina" es "buena vida"?

Tags: vocabulario, etimología, modismos, méxico

El Diccionario de la lengua define [**vida capulina**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=blw7uSa) como

> 1. f. Méx. **buena vida.**

y [**capulina**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7MrwTuc) como

> 3. f. Méx. **Araña negra muy venenosa.**

¿Cómo se llegó a que la combinación de "vida" con "araña venenosa" significara "buena vida"?

Comment: Is not one of the other meanings for capuline more likely here? i reminds me of the English saying Life is just a bowl of cherries.

Comment: @mdewey the use of "capulina" as "cherry" is used in Cuba but not in Mexico. The asker was trying to match the meanings for the same country.

Answer (score 3):

Son cosas distintas: por un lado está la expresión *vida capulina* y por el otro la *araña capulina*.

Vemos primero que el diccionario de americanismos define *capulín* como:

> [**capulín**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=ykKHLlv8px0AIUeuhjS). (Del nahua *capulín*, **cerezo**).
>   I.  1.  m. Mx, Ho, ES, Ni. Árbol de copa ancha, corteza marrón rojizo o grisácea, flores blancas pequeñas y fruto pequeño. (Rosaceae; Prunus capuli). ◆ xegua.
>   2.  Mx, Ho, ES, Ni. Fruto del capulín, comestible, de color rojo intenso y similar a una guinda pequeña. (Rosaceae; Prunus capuli).
>   3.  Gu, Ho, ES, Ni. ixpepe.
>   4.  Gu, Ho, ES, Ni. majagüillo, árbol.
>   5.  CR, Pa. Árbol de hasta 20 m de altura, de hojas simples y alternas, flores rosadas y fruto capsular de color marrón o negro cuando están maduros. (Tiliaceae; Trichospermum galeottii). ◆ majaguillo.

Por ello, la *vida capulina* parece que se refiere a aquella en la que uno está subido a un cerezo, en su *dolce farniente* particular. Por otro lado, la araña probablemente reciba este nombre porque su color y forma se parece a la forma del fruto de ese cerezo.

En *Vocabulario del uayeísmo en la cultura de Yucatán*, de Jesús Amaro Gamboa, 1999, leo las siguientes definiciones:

> **Capón, na** s. y adj. Animal castrado; por antonomasia el gallo. (...) El adjetivo capona aplicase [sic] a la vida regalada que también se apellina Capulina. ¡Qué vida más *capona* la de Francisco! ¡está dedicado a la vida capulina! (V. Chirmole, repollo, repollado, repochón, capulín, capulina). Vida capone es equivalente al italiano "dolce farniente". Huevonería (Dolche farniente, indolencia, grata holganza).
>
> **Capulín, na, namente**
>   Souza habla de un capulín de Yucatán, clasificado como *Muntinga calabura*, L. Filiáceas, y de un capulincillo *Conostegia xalapensis*, L., de la familia de las melastonáceas; pero no del capulín veradero, de la familia de las rosáceas, *Prunus capuli*, Cav. que sí hemos conocido como planta que, aunque rara, vive en Yucatán. Por lo demás el interés de esta palabra no estriba en su significación botánica sino en su connotación psicológica: capulina, como adjetivo, califica a la vida regalada y fácil: "Fulano lleva una vida *capulina*", es decir, que vive sabrosamente o, más bien, en la abundancia; una vida regalada, "se da una vida *capulina*"; "viva *capulinamente*". (...)

Leo después en *De los descubrimientos a las taxonomías: La botánica y la zoología en la lengua española del Renacimiento a la Ilustración*, de Matteo De Beni, 2015, otras informaciones que parecen confirmar estas hipótesis:

> 5.5. Capulín (elocapolin, 47v), Ardisia
>
> La primera documentación en el CORDE es de 1560 (Franciso Cervantes de Salazar, *Crónica de la Nueva España*, p. II, 59): "En este camino, yendo muy cansado un español, se subió sobre un *capulí*, que los españoles llaman 'cerezo'". Por la definición en el DRAE se puede deducir que reciben este nombre planas que pertenecen a diferentes familias, tanto árboles como arbustos, y se emplen como sinónimos la forma más cercana del étimo (*capulí*) y el masculino y femenino hispanizados con un sufijo pseudo-diminutivo (*capulín* y *capulina*):
>
> **capulí**. (Del náhuatl *capollí*).
>   1. m. Árbol de América, de la familia de las Rosáceas, que alcanza unos quince metros de altura, especie de cerezo, que da un fruto de gusto y olor agradables.
>   2. m. Fruto de este árbol.
>   (...)
>
> **capulín**. (De or. náhuatl).
>   1. m. **capulí** (| árbol rosáceo).
>   2. m. coloq. El Salv. favor.
>   3. m. Méx. **capulina** (| cereza que produce el capulí).
>
> **capulina**.
>   1. f. Am. Cereza que produce el capulí.
>   2. f. Cuba. **capulí** (| árbol tiliáceo).
>   3. f. Méx. Araña negra muy venenosa.
>   4. f.p. us. **prostituta**.

Tirando un poco del hilo de la araña (je, je) veo que [la araña capulina es la Latrodectus mactans, conocida también como viuda negra](http://www.bcsnoticias.mx/las-dos-aranas-mas-letales-de-mexico-viven-en-los-hogares-de-la-paz/). Véamosla:

> [image]

Ahora fijémonos en el fruto del capulín:

> [image]

Visto de lejos, ¡se parecen! De ahí seguramente el uso de *araña capulina*.

Comment: Buena respuesta. A pesar del comentario a @mdewey, resulta que en México se usa "capulín" con el mismo significado de "capulina" (cereza), lo certifican el DRAE y el diccionario de americanismos, así que al final mdewey tenía razón, la frase se puede asemejar a la inglesa del "bowl of cherries".

Comment: @CarlosAlejo sí, efectivamente. Luego la _araña capulina_ se llama así por su semejanza con el fruto del árbol.

Comment: @fedorqui: muy interesante respuesta, pero que inevitablemente lleva a la pregunta ¿por qué está limitada a México, si la acepción capulina = cereza es tan general en Hispanoamérica? ¿Por qué no hay una expresión similar con _cereza_ en España, como _vida cereza_?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo perhaps you need a trip to Mexico to carry out a comparative study of the two fruits. Perhaps the Mexican ones are just much nicer than Spanish cherries. Time to apply for a research grant.

Comment: @mdewey I need trips to so many places...

Answer (score 1):

No creo que finalmente podamos saber cuál es la relación etimológica, pero ésta es mi sugerencia:

Primero, por una obvia similitud física con el fruto del **capulín**, a una araña se le empieza a decir *araña capulina*. De hecho en el [Diccionario del Español de México](https://books.google.cl/books?id=GqDQCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT419&ots=aCs-1mwbuz&dq=Ara%C3%B1a%20negra%20muy%20venenosa%2C%20de%20aspecto%20semejante%20al%20de%20un%20capul%C3%ADn&pg=PT419#v=onepage&q=Ara%C3%B1a%20negra%20muy%20venenosa,%20de%20aspecto%20semejante%20al%20de%20un%20capul%C3%ADn&f=false) se indica esta analogía:

> **capulina** s f **1** (*Lathrodectus mactans*) Araña negra muy venenosa, de aspecto semejante al de un capulín [...]

Luego, dado que uno de los significados de [*araña*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3P8VE21) es **prostituta** (y parece que este uso es bastante frecuente en México), la palabra *capulina* pasa a designar a una mujer que ejerce el comercio sexual y *lo capulino* pasa a designar *lo prostibulario*.

Por último, la palabra con el paso del tiempo se "suaviza" y hace común, perdiendo la connotación pecaminosa del burdel, pero manteniendo el sentido de "placer", "voluptuosidad" y finalmente **"buena vida"**.

Queda en la duda saber por qué existe la analogía **prostituta/araña**. Tal vez a las prostitutas se les dice "arañas" porque -dadas las circunstancias- son consideradas "mujeres malas" (por las esposas, por ejemplo). El símbolo de la [**viuda negra**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viuda_negra_(asesina)) (mujer que asesina hombres) se basa precisamente en la misma especie *Lathrodectus mactans*, la araña capulina, conocida por devorar la hembra al macho después de copular.

Answer (score 0):

Acá en El Salvador hay algo parecido con esa expresión, pero hace referencia a cuando haces un favor: "haceme un capulinaso" es como "hey, haceme un favor"; obviamente, en su sentido coloquial.